# Recovering a quadratic form from a finite set of values

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming

Say I want to recover the matrix of a positive quadratic form from its values on a finite collection of points. That is, given vectors $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and the values $x_i^TAx_i$, I want to find the positive semidefinite matrix $A$. I know this can be written as a semidefinite program, but is there a more clever way that exposes more of the structure of the problem, or conditions for when it can and can't be done?

Edit: For clarity, I am not giving myself freedom to choose the $x_i$; I want to address the problem with arbitrarily sampled points.

Comment: $A$ has at most $\frac12n(n+1)$ degrees of freedom (perhaps fewer, but I’m not sure that semidefiniteness does anything for you in this regard). You will need that many independent constraints on its entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_i = \begin{pmatrix}x_i^1 \\ \vdots \\ x_i^n \end{pmatrix}$ for $1\leq i \leq m$ and $(A)_{ij} = a^{ij}$. The quadratic form $q(x_i) = x_iA^Tx_i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a^{jj}(x_i^j)^2 + \sum\limits_{k=1 \\ k < j}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n (2a^{jk})x_i^jx_i^k$. This is a summation of $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ terms. Define an index $1\leq \ell\leq \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ for the terms in the sum, and let $b^\ell$ be the coefficients and $y_i^\ell$ be the $x_i$-products. Define the matrix $(Y)_{i\ell} = y_i^\ell$ and the vectors $(B)_\ell = b^\ell$ and $(Q)_i = q(x_i)$, so that the equation $YB=Q$ represents the $m$ simultaneous linear equations for the $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ coefficients of the quadratic form.

Using this framework, we can see the condition for determining $A$:

If $m\geq\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and there exists a matrix $Y'$ constructed from $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ distinct rows of $Y$ such that $\det Y' \neq 0$, then $B = (Y')^{-1}Q'$, where $Q'$ is the vector constructed from those same rows of $Q$. Then, $A$ can be determined from $B$.